# Running Recipe for Puppet on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, puppet

I am new to Puppet world. I have Ubuntu 11.04 (64bit) server and client. I have installed the latest version of puppet server and client. The Puppet configuration running successfully. I am able to connect to the server from my client.

I want to write a recipe to install Apache2 on my client. Can anybody tell me the link or a step by step creation process of a puppet recipe to install Apache2 on my client? How to run and where to run these recipes?

Where do I see the error files? How can I know my recipes are working correctly?

The init.pp file is

```
file  {"password": 
    name=>"/etc/passwd",
    owner =>"root",
    group =>"bin",
    mode=>644,
} 

class apache{ 
    package { httpd: ensure => installed }
    service{ "httpd" : 
        name => $operatingsystem ?{
                    debian=>"apache2",
                    redhat=>"httpd",
                    default =>"apache",
                    CentOS=>"httpd",
                 },
         ensure=> running,
         require=>Package["httpd"],
   }
 }

node 'myclientname'{
    include apache
} 

# All of the nodes that don't have definitions associated with the will use
# the following node definition.
node default {
    case $operatingsystem {
        CentOS: { include apache }
        default: {}
    }
 }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You might have more luck asking this on http://askubuntu.com.

Comment: i have written the init.pp on server. Run by puppet apply --verbose init.pp --noop. My client doesnt have apache installed. I am getting info: Applying configuration version '1318681308' notice: /Stage[main]//File[password]/group: is root, should be bin (noop). what should i do and where to check the conf is write or wrong. where to see the log.

Comment: myinit.pp-- file {"password": 02name=>"/etc/passwd", 03 owner =>"root",04 group =>"bin",05 mode=>644,06 } 08class apache{ 09 10 package { httpd: ensure => installed } 11 12 service{ "httpd" : 13 14name => $operatingsystem ?{15 debian=>"apache2",16 redhat=>"httpd",17 default =>"apache",18CentOS=>"httpd",19 },20ensure=> running,21 require=>Package["httpd"],22 }23 }2425 node 'myclientname'{26 include apache 27 } 28#Allothernodestheydon'thavedefinitions associated with the will usethe following nodedefinition. 2930node default {31 case $operatingsystem {32CentOS:{includeapache}33 default: {}34}35}

Comment: You should edit all that into your question (which will also bump it on the 'Active' page so it gets more attention).

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you there's already an /etc/password file who's group is root instead of bin.  Since the /etc/password file doesn't have anything to do with installing apache, so I recommend removing the entire file block.

Other things you may want to look at:

- The package name for apache is going to change based on the operating system, so it won;t always be 'httpd'
- You may want to include an "enable => true" to your service so apache will start on boot.